# Batch process in V2 supported?

Tags: batch-processing, intuit-partner-platform

Is batch processing supported with V2 directly (without using the SDKs)? I can't find any discussion of this in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Without devkit, batch process is not possible. Batch support is present in V2 but it sends each request separately. For Ex - for 10 objects, there will be 10 different transactions(IO).

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0100_ipp_.net_devkit/0300_asynchronous_calls/2_batch_process

Just fyi - Actual batch operation support is available in V3.
For ex - 10 objects can be created(or any other CRUD operations), using only 1 transaction.

**V3** - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/020_key_concepts/00700_batch_operation

**.net devkit -** https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0201_ipp_java_devkit_3.0

Thanks